# Site compatibility issue with IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I built a website that was doing fine on all browsers, until I downloaded IE9. On the homepage, there is text that just does not show up in ie9. The link to my site is [www.totalrecallsolutions.com/corporate](http://www.totalrecallsolutions.com/corporate/) The homepage is called index.html, and the text on the six main tabs in the center are not visible, as well as a slogan that is supposed to be under the logo. I would really appreciate any help anyone has to offer, as I am at a total loss! Compare the site to the way it looks in IE8, and you can see what's missing when you view it in IE9. 
I'd appreciate any help!!
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to venture a guess that these  tags are not getting processed by IE9 . You should check compatibility with the folks supporting that library.
Here is a post that might help:
http://blog.ninanet.com/2011/04/29/cufon-and-ie9

Comment: Wow, thanks Dmitry. That solved it! It's showing now, although in a different font, which I have to figure out why, but thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to hear it! don't forget to check it off as the correct answer :)

Comment: First, uptick my answer with an arrow above the Zero to the left of my answer. Then, click the hollow checkmark underneath that.